# Dynamically creating tables in SQLite with user input in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm quite new to Android and the SQLite. I'm currently working on an app which requires user to create list of their favourite artists.

I have implemented some charts which already display this artist data. I believe I can easily figure out how to implement adding data to lists.

I was thinking of having two separate tables in SQLite :

- Lists (which would store the list names which the user has created)
- ChartItems (which would store the chart items and the lists they belong to)

However the Lists table only needs one field in this case "ListName" so I thought it might not be crucial to have a table for this.

Is it possible to dynamically create tables when getting input from a user?

For example : A user creates a list and that value is subsequently used to create a table.

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I like the two table method better, with a "listId" field to link them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to be creating new tables on the fly. Your proposal for two tables is fine. The list table should have at least two fields - an integer field called id or _id which is the primary key, and a text field for the list name. The Chartitems table will have a field (listid) which holds the id of the list to which it belongs. This means a chartitem can belong to only one list, and adding a chartitem to a list is achieved by setting the listid field in its record. This is a one-to-many relationship.

If you want to have a single chartitem in more than one list, then you need a many-to-many relationship, which is implemented by having a third table (links). This table will have one field mapping to a list (listid), and one field mapping to a chartitem (itemid.) To add a chartitem to a list, you create the appropriate link entry in the links table. In this case the chartitem table does not need the listid field.

I suggest reading up some more on relationships in databases to clarify these concepts. One principle I strongly suggest following is to have *every* table contain a field called id which is the primary key for that table, and use that for all references from other tables. In the long run this works much better than using other fields (like name) in relationships.